# 1980 Civic hatchback clutch won't engage but gears are felt

Tags: honda, civic, clutch, manual-transmission

I am looking at buying a 1980 Civic hatchback but the clutch needs work. He says that you can feel the gears but it won't engage. Does that mean it needs a new clutch or transmission fluid?

Comment: Can you add any additional information?  Does the car run?  Did you try shifting it while it was running?

Comment: You can typically check the transmission fluid levels by just unbolting the top fill plug and feeling where the level is. There should also be a clutch inspection plate that you can undo to help gauge how much clutch material is left.

Comment: @KevinEvans Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Zaid I'm not sure if that is the issue or not, there's like way too many reasons that the clutch won't engage properly

Comment: Could be the clutch isn't releasing.  Try to start it with the shifter in first or reverse.  Could also be an issue in the differential, one of the axles, or inside the transmission.

Answer (score 3):

This clutch is very basic, it is cable activated, it has a conventional push type throwout bearing. It has no inspection cover for viewing the clutch disk thickness.
The transmission is lubricated with regular engine oil; its condition would not effect clutch engagement.

The two most common causes of lack of engagement are a broken actuator cable and worn clutch disk.

Another common failure of this transmission is the front mainshaft bearing. This causes lots of noise but does not affect the clutch. Clutch replacement is considered simple by experienced technicians.